# Why in cloud run domain mapping it takes so long to map my service to a domain in GoDaddy?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have a frontend in cloud run I want to map to a domain purchased in DoDaddy (breadfree.es) for a demo, but after configuring it in Domain mapping it has taken up to 16 hours and it still does not work. Can you give me any advice? I read it takes from 4 to 8 hours for the dns to propagate, and also that for some it works deleting the records and putting them again (in a link below). Is there any other solution that works in GoDaddy?

Also, it is so strange to me because I have discovered although the domain is not mapped, if I map this service to a subdomain, it is propagated faster. I mapped it with tienda.breadfree.es, and it works, although I prefer it to be map to breadfree.es (tienda means shop in Spanish).

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

[Google Cloud Run - Domain Mapping stuck at Certificate Provisioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789565/google-cloud-run-domain-mapping-stuck-at-certificate-provisioning)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general for Cloud Run (fully managed) it takes 24 hours until the domain is propagated. Even though the SSL certificate can take less than 15 minutes the full process will take up to 24 hours.

This process can take as much as 24 hours because of the certificates and the time needed to be issues and renewed. Indeed, when you map a service to a custom domain like yours (tienda) a managed certificate is automatically issued but for a domain it takes more and it is not automatically issued.

You could try what you posted in the StackOverflow post but you should wait and see after 24 hours if the domain is still not working. Usually if the domain is still not working after 24 hours probably something went wrong in the configuration phase or a step was skipped and I suggest you to open a support ticket in order to check with the Google Team what is the issue.

Comment: I tried to change the record: I mean delete it and put again breadfree.es and the IP the one that GCP shows, but after 2 hours nothing happened. . .so, I think getting to breadfree.es it is not possible.

Comment: PS: I didn't tell because I forgot, but after trying several time of putting and deleting the records, it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use - https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/
This will tell you Time To Live (TTL). For information on TTL check this link (https://support.google.com/a/answer/48090?hl=en)