# Google Cloud Run Domain Mapping with Google DNS stuck on certificate issuance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have registered a domain using Google Cloud Domains and I would like to map it to a Google Cloud Run service. I have correctly added the DNS record but the process is stuck! I have also read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789565/google-cloud-run-domain-mapping-stuck-at-certificate-provisioning) but the problem they faced was related to CloudFlare and I am not using that.

As you see I have set the record correctly, but it's been hours and the the status is still pending showing `Waiting for certificate provisioning. You must configure your DNS records for certificate issuance to begin.`

Is Google Cloud buggy, or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Google Cloud is asking for this:

[image]

Comment: 1) If you mask the domain name, we cannot test what is wrong. 2) Use a public DNS validation tool and verify that the DNS resource records Google asked you to create are correct. I use mxtoolbox. 3) If the records are correct, cancel the certificate process and try again.

Comment: @JohnHanley: I have checked the DNS and it is live in a all locations around the world. I have tried for like 100 times. I cannot show you my domain name publicly here.

Comment: @JohnHanley: I even moved to cloudflare but it didn't work either. I guess it's bug. It's sad to see that Google Cloud is buggy like that.

Comment: What is **live in all locations around the world**? You must be very detailed in your problem description. For example, if you previously configured a DNS resource record wrong and a query retuned NXDOMAIN, you are stuck until the timeout specified in the SOA. When you configure a public DNS server, you must configure it 100% correct the first time, otherwise caching and TTLs kick in.

Comment: @ArnoldZahrneinder, I don't think it is, but if you think this is a bug, please file a bug with G.

Comment: After 24 hours (the upper limit for [SSL certificate provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#run)), does the status stay the same? Cloud Run domain mappings is also not yet fully released, so retrying the mapping from scratch could help. Have you also tried the solutions shown in the [troubleshooting section](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#custom-domain-mappings)? Without sharing full details like the domain name, the next step is to open a [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases) directly with GCP.

Comment: @ErnestoC: It never worked. It made so frustrated that we had to give up Google Cloud and switch back to AWS. Google cloud services sounded very intriguing in the begging but we faced a lot of unexpected problems particularly with the VPC.

Comment: I know AWS and Google Cloud very well. Both have excellent services and I have no problems with either one.

Comment: @JohnHanley: Me too, but AWS does not hang when binding a domain to a service!

Comment: Cloud Run does not hang while waiting for a certificate to be issued. You can continue to use the generated URL. The key is you configured your DNS server wrong. It is really that simple.

Comment: @JohnHanley: It isn't wrong as I check it with many different tools in many different regions. Google Cloud is carrying Google's name so I except it to be quite fast much less irresponsive. But it didn't work. My comments about Google Cloud is not relevant in SO, but I just wanted to reflect it so that someone at Google Cloud would feel responsible to inspect the issue and fix it.

Comment: I am part of Google Cloud Support; to look deeper into this issue, you could open a [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases) to review your configuration and create a formal issue report if necessary.