# Waiting for Certificate provisioning when mapping custom domain to Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-dns

Trying to map a custom domain to an app deployed on Cloud Run.

Running into this issue: "Waiting for certificate provisioning. You must configure your DNS records for certificate issuance to begin."

Referred to this issue:
[Google Cloud Run - Domain Mapping stuck at Certificate Provisioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789565/google-cloud-run-domain-mapping-stuck-at-certificate-provisioning)

Am I missing a step or should I keep waiting?

Steps I took:

- Added mapping with service and domain name.
- Configured a Cloud DNS Zone and updated the DNS records on the domain host.
- Linked the Cloud DNS Zone to a Cloud Domain.
- Verified with TXT file google-site-verification=....
- Used https://dnspropagation.net/ to monitor and it seems like regions Costa Rica and Indonesia are having trouble propagating.

Comment: 1) Make sure that you correctly created the DNS resource records before Google Cloud checks, otherwise, your DNS server returns NXDOMAIN and you could wait for that response to expire. 2) If it has been over 24 hours, delete the custom mapping and start over. If the DNS resource records are correct, the custom mapping takes only a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that it is still provisioning. But you can consider checking the following :

1. Make sure that your [SSL's scope](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#ssl_certificate_scope) is global.
2. A-record for your domain should be properly configured.
3. You can try using [SSL Shopper](https://www.sslshopper.com/) or [WhatsmyDNS](https://www.whatsmydns.net/) to monitor and check the propagation status of your domain.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem earlier, where the "Waiting for Certificate Provisioning..." was taking too long.

In GCP's [official](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting) site, it says it may take from **15 to 60 mins** to propagate changes.

Took around 20mins for me to see the error go away after the changes were propagated.